# Image Capture Specific part of screen

Tags: java, screenshot, bufferedimage

I'm trying to capture a specific part of my screen and save it as a JPG image. 
This is what I've tried thus far:

```
        Robot r = new Robot(); 
        // It saves screenshot to desired path 
        String path = "Health_Bar.JPG"; 

        // Used to get ScreenSize and capture image 
        //Dimension dim = new Dimension(376, 54, 58, 18);
        Rectangle capture =  
        new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()); 
        BufferedImage Image = r.createScreenCapture( new Rectangle(191, 229, 473, 150) );//r.createScreenCapture(capture); 
        ImageIO.write(Image, "jpg", new File(path)); 
        System.out.println("Screenshot saved");
```

This code is not working as expected. I expect the x and y coordinate to be the top left corner coordinate of the image captured. And even though this is true in some cases i.e. if x,y=0; it is not in most other cases i.e x=191, y=229, as in the example code above. 
For the example code above this is the out I get [output image from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xOku.jpg). However this is the image I expect to get [Image of expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG4b9.jpg). The coordinates in image 2 (expected output image) is the coordinate for the top left corner of the "Mofiki's Coordinate Finder" window.
Can anyone explain whats going on and how to fix it?

Comment: I found that when I change my screen resolution to 1280 x 1024 it works just fine. Changed it from 1920 x 1080 to that.

Comment: I have resolved the problem, in display settings there is an option "change the size of text, apps, and other items" which was set to 125%. after I changed it to 100% the programmed worked as intended.